# Apex Trigger from Managed Package - throwing error in community

Tags: trigger, managed-package, permissions

We have installed a Rio Inventory+ Managed Package into an Enterprise edition Salesforce instance. (Appexchange link: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009xLvGEAU)

This package works great if the user has a Salesforce license. However, once we try and use its functionality in the community, it throws errors.

For instance, as a Salesforce user, if I go into an Opportunity and add products to it, related inventory will be adjusted based on the product and quantity. However, when I attempt to do the same thing in the Partner Community, I see this lovely error:

> Apex trigger readymade_inv.UpdateOppProduct caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: readymade_inv.UpdateOppProduct:
>   execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.SecurityException:
>   ViewAllData or ViewAllRecords required to access external id fields
>   which do not have a unique index: (readymade_inv)

If anyone has run into this before, know how to remedy this, or know of a way to bypass a trigger from a Managed Package, I would be eternally grateful.

Thank you,
Michael